# Отсутствие класса в Support Library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

Пытался импортировать android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView в свой класс в Eclipse.

Среда никак не хотела воспринимать это как существующий объект, и в конце концов я полез рыться в саппорт лайбрари. Что я там обнаружил, повергло меня в шок - такого класса там не было.

Я его не удалял ниоткуда, SDK Manager показывает, что библиотека скачана полностью и обновлений нет. Странно получать такие проблемы, имея дело с продуктами такой компании, как Google.

Понимаю, что вопрос не очень достойный внимания, но все же прошу направить меня на путь решения этой проблемы, так или иначе.

Скриншот выложить не могу по причине маленького рейтинга.

P.S. В Build Path все верно, существующие классы подхватываются на ура.

Comment: Версия support library какая у вас? Не та, что в sdk, а та, что в проекте используется.

Comment: А где можно посмотреть? Не задавался раньше таким вопросом

Comment: скриншот на radikal.ru  и ссылку сюда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RecyclerView - это отдельная либа, кою надо подключать отдельно.

Т.е. повторите действия с SupportLibrary, добавив в workspace (а потом и к своему проекту в виде либы) проект RecyclerView, коий должен лежать в папке

> sdk\extras\android\support\v7

Comment: спасибо, помогло